# Is bare first order logic without equality an empty language?

Tags: first-order-logic

Suppose we are considering first-order logic without equality without any relation symbols. Since there are no relation symbols, not even equality, does this mean that this language is empty?

Comment: I would still usually consider $\top$, $\bot$, $(\forall x) (\exists y) (\top \vee \bot)$, etc. to be in the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yes - if you additionally outlaw the nullary connectives $\top$ and $\perp$, then indeed there are no well-formed formulas in this system. (Of course if you include them then Daniel Schepler's comment applies.)